# Question on Measures and Data Filters in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder, filters

I have an email which is sent as triggered send in Journey Builder. A few days into this being active, I noticed that one of the links was wrong (too many http:// notations) and so I changed the template and re-published the email template. The link is now correct and works perfectly.

However, I've been asked to do an email send to all the people who had the wrong link.

The first part I did manually - I exported the list of clicks from the tracking report, cut it down to only those who had the wrong link, then re-imported it to Marketing Cloud into a Data Extension.

The problem is, the email has some dynamic content and personalisation such as `%%firstname%%` and `%%surveylink%%`, which are not present in the new Data Extension.

I tried making a measure and data filter but got a bit lost and kept getting 0 subscribers.

What measure/data filter combination would I need to do something like:

> Find all subscribers who received JobId 12345 and clicked a link that begins with "http://http://"?

Edit: So I've managed to pull through the firstname, but not a neighbouring column I need with the survey link in it. I get this:

[image]

In that first 'Here:' is supposed to be %%=v(@linkurl)=%% and the red image should link to it, and doesn't. Interestingly, when you do a send preview, the 'text' version of the email shows, but the html version doesn't. So I think my ampscript is ok.

Comment: is all the information that you need for the personalization strings stored inside of a single data extension (I know it is not the one with the subscribers you wish to send to)?

Comment: Hi @Gortonington, yes it is. It has found firstname and email but it is refusing to pick up something from a column called SurveyLink_1. It does show in the text version of the email but not the html version - it won't link! See image I added to main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the personalization info you need is in an all subscribers attribute, you dont need it to be in the data extension, just use the personalization strings you indicated.

Personalization strings always check for a match on all subscribers profile attributes as well as the DE audience.

If they are not, you can use ampscript functions in the body of the email to pull from wherever the data is located.

Supposing that firstname is a column in a DE called 'subscribers', and that this DE has an 'emailaddress' column you could do this:

```
%%[
set @email = [email address] 
set @firstname = Lookup('subscribers','firstname','emailaddress',@email) 
]%%
```

This lookup function basically says return the value of firstname from the DE 'subscribers' where emailaddress equals this specific subscribers email address, then assign that value to @firstname.

To have it write to the html, instead of %%firstname%%, write:

```
%%=v(@firstname)=%%
```

Regarding your data filter question: I dont believe you can filter on tracking data with a data view without a solution like Audience builder.

You could, however, build a query activity and join in whatever columns were needed. This would return all the subscribers who meet your criteria:

```
select subscriberkey from _click 
where jobid = 12345
where linkcontent like 'http://http://%'
```

From that point, you'd want to add an inner join, likely on subscriber key, to include whatever other columns you'd like in your sendable DE.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried setting the variable with a lookup, and have managed to retrieve the firstname, and that is working fine. However it's also trying to retrieve a link from a column called SurveyLink_1. In the send preview, the image that is set to link to this with %%=RedirectTo(@linkurl)=%% is not linking to anything - you can't click it. Interestingly, when you preview the Text version of the email, it DOES pull the link through correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the content of @linkurl? It should contain a fully qualified link.  And make sure you are using only RedirectTo(), not v().

Comment: OK I'm not sure what happened but I directly copied the html code from the original email and it worked. Seems like it was just a bug. Send report shows me that people are clicking on fully working links. Thanks for your help!